# working with big scientific data on Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdf5, netcdf

I am currently starting  a project titled "Cloud computing for time series mining algorithms using Hadoop".
The data which I have is hdf files of size over a terabyte.In hadoop as I know that we should have text files as input for further processing (map-reduce task). So I have one option that I convert all my .hdf files to text files which is going to take a lot of time.

Or I find a way of how to use raw hdf files in map reduce programmes.
So far I have not been successful in finding any java code which reads hdf files and extract data from them.
If somebody has a better idea of how to work with hdf files I will really appreciate such help.

Thanks
Ayush

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first option, you could use a conversion tool like [HDF dump](http://theory.asu.ru/~ivan/devel/hdfdump) to dump HDF file to text format. Otherwise,  you can write a program using Java library for reading HDF file and write it to text file.

For your second option, SciHadoop is a good example of how to read Scientific datasets from Hadoop. It uses NetCDF-Java library to read NetCDF file. Hadoop does not support POSIX API for file IO. So, it uses an extra software layer to translate POSIX call of NetCDF-java library to HDFS(Hadoop) API calls. If SciHadoop does not already support HDF files, you might go along a little harder path and develop a similar solution yourself.

Comment: Thanks the first option seems more reasonable for me.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some resources:

- [SciHadoop](http://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~alkis/papers/sc11_scihadoop.pdf) (uses netCDF but might be already extended to HDF5).
- You can either use [JHDF5](https://wiki-bsse.ethz.ch/pages/viewpage.action;jsessionid=2DF2048AFA49926DA292581C0B4FF953?pageId=26609113) or the lower level official [Java HDF5 interface](http://www.hdfgroup.org/hdf-java-html/) to read out data from any HDF5 file in the map-reduce task.

Comment: thanks. Do you know of some tutorial to learn using this(the second option)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not find any java code and can do in other languages then you can use hadoop streaming.

Comment: what is Hadoop piping and how does it assist with reading HDF5?

Answer (score 1):

SciMATE http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~wayi/papers/SciMATE.pdf is a good option. It is developed based on a variant of MapReduce, which has been shown to perform a lot of scientific applications much more efficiently than Hadoop.